# null error when throwing an exception comparing elements in a list

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm comparing a Json object if it has different values, to achieve this, I created a list and I'm extracting the elements from the dto, and adding it to the new list.

If the elements inside the list don't match throw an error from a class created named "ExceptionHandler".

the error message works for all other validation but with this one is returning null !!

```
core.exception.ExceptionHandler: null
```

The object that I'm trying to compare is the "PaymentProcessor"
{

```
    "items": [
    {
        "paymentProcessor": "VISA",
        "type": "CARD",
        "refferedType": "RECHARGE",
    },
    {
        "paymentProcessor": "xx",
        "type": "CARD",
        "referredType": "RECHARGE",
    }
]
```

}

the code:

```
       List<String> paymentProcessor = new ArrayList<>();

    for(Items item : initiatePaymentDto.getItems()){
        if(item.getPaymentProcessor()==null){
            throw  new ExceptionHandler("PaymentProcessor Must not Be null!");
        }
        if(item.getAmount()==null){
            throw new ExceptionHandler("Amount Must not Be null!");

        }
        paymentProcessor.add(item.getPaymentProcessor());
    }


    if(Collections.frequency(paymentProcessor, paymentProcessor.get(0)) == paymentProcessor.size()==false){
        throw  new ExceptionHandler("Multiple payment processor is not supported!");
    }
```

exception class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ExceptionHandler extends Throwable {

    private String errorDetails;
}
```

controller:

```
@PostMapping(path="/paymentProcess")
public PaymentResponse paymentProcess(@RequestBody 

PaymentProcessDto initiatePaymentDto) throws ExceptionHandler {
        return pyamentProcessService.paymentProcessRequest(initiatePaymentDto);
        }
```